# Docker container stops running only when volume is attached

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, docker-volume

I have written a dockerfile that runs mysql on an ubuntu image. The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server
RUN sed -i '43s/.*/bind-address            = 0.0.0.0/' /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
EXPOSE 3306
ENTRYPOINT service mysql start && bash
```

If I run:

```
docker run -dit mysql-server
```

after building the container everything works fine and my Apache/PHP container can communicate with it. However, if I run it with a volume attached (`docker run -dit -v ~/vol/:/var/lib/mysql/ mysql-server`) the container will stop running after 30 seconds (I'm pretty sure it's the same amount of time every time).

Does anyone know a way I can keep the container up and mount a volume? I've never had this problem before and can't find anything else online (I've been looking a while). Thanks.

Comment: Anything from `docker logs`?

Comment: What's different between ~/vol and what exists inside the image at that location? Don't forget to check file permissions and uid/gid ownership of the files.

Comment: can you try replacing in the ENTRYPOINT `&& bash` by `&& sleep infinity`?

Comment: Not much from docker logs just:  * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                        No directory, logging in with HOME=/
                                                                        [ fail]     (with fail turning into OK if a volume isn't present). Also here's the what a got when I ll'd /var/lib/mysql: `drwxrwxr-x  4  1002  1003 4096 Feb  8 02:25 mysql`.

Comment: There was no difference replacing && bash with && sleep infinity, the container crashed after 30 seconds. Also the ~/vol folder has 775 permissions.

Comment: This has to do with the owner of your `/var/lib/mysql` folder. When you run your container without mounting a directory: owner will be mysql:mysql but when you mount it will be probably something as 1000:1000

Comment: Yeah, I did notice that the. owner and permissions were different when a volume was added. I added `chmod 700 /var/lib/mysql && chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql` to the Dockerfile (trying it in the entrypoint and then in a run), which did manage to change the owner and permissions successfully, but unfortunately the container still crashed after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are masking the contents of `/var/lib/mysql` with the contents of `~/vol` which I'm assuming is empty. As such the MySQL server can't start as it's missing database files. I would personally use the official image over your custom implementation as it will handle what your looking for [here is the link to Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/). It has options for mounting your custom `my.cnf` file if you need those changes. However by default the image does bind to 0.0.0.0. See the Dockerhub link for config options.

Hope this helps

Dylan

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I'm using the official image now and it works great. I just wanted to understand why adding a volume keeps crashing it. What you said makes sense, although even with all the correct data in `~/var` (copied out of another container via a different volume), my container keeps crashing. I think perhaps a combination of this and changing some permissions might work? My current solution to this problem is to mount a volume elsewhere and run a cronjob to copy everything over (which is quite ugly). I  definitely think getting a firmer understanding of how Docker containers work. Thanks!

Comment: Glad its helped solve your issues - as a general rule rather than rolling your own Docker images I would go with official ones as a base and make any customisations on top as they are really very good. Permissions in Docker can be a pain I'd recommend a `chown -R root:root <DIR>` after a copy like that just to explicitly define your permissions and rule that out. As long as the files have a UID of zero i.e root it should avoid any permission related issues. May I ask why you need this copy? Also if this resolved it please mark as resolved :) Will be happy to help further just shout